# I can access MariaDB with any non setted user

Tags: nginx, mariadb

I have a big problem. When i enter into my server as root and type:

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u test_user -p
```

Note the user test_user doesn´t exist and i can even enter in the MariaDB without a password too.

What i can do to config the security in mariadb that not any user has access?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete user with empty name, like described in
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html, under "Removing anonymous accounts" section

Comment: thanks but i also found this that helped me https://kb.askmonty.org/en/mysql_secure_installation/